# Is there a possible way to assign Elastic IP to every container in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am trying to build an architecture something like shown in the image [image]

What I want to establish is that every docker image that i deploy in the ECS should have an individual ip address and should be accessible through a password protection when accessed through a portal.

But first i will like to know a way to assign them a elastic ip to all the ECS containers deployed.

Comment: Do you really need an Elastic IP? There is a soft limit of 5 Elastic IP's per user. If a static domain name is acceptable I would suggest to use Route53.

Comment: can you help me with route53 @FelipeSulser